# How could I find an application window via it's ClassID?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automation, automated-tests, white-framework

I'm using **White** for test automation. I had created simple application test, which is tracking an application via it's dialog name.

```
var appCalc = Application.AttachOrLaunch(new ProcessStartInfo("application.exe"));
var wndCalc = appCalc.GetWindow("Dialog caption");
```

But this approach is unstable, because in different localisations, the caption could differ. How could i track my application, using it's ClassID?

Comment: What is ClassID? Do you mean ClassName?

Comment: Yes, you're right. There is a mistake in my question. I know the ClassName

Comment: Is that the MainWindow? Should be possible to derive that from the Process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var wndCalc = appCalc.GetWindow(SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Your class name"), InitializeOption.NoCache);
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using searching in colection, received from appCalc.GetWindows(). Your solution is more optimal