# Finding a desktop window by class in White

Tags: c#, automation, automated-tests, white-framework

I'm building an automated test suite using White. One of the things I need to do is click on an icon in the System Promoted Notification Area (bottom right bit of the Start bar). I'm having trouble identifying it to White though. Using Spy++, I've discovered that it's nested three layers deep in windows that have no caption to search, which is the normal way White identifies windows. I'm therefore trying to find the correct window by class.

According to Spy++, I first need to get window 10042, which has the class "Shell_TrayWnd". Then its child window 10048, with class TrayNotifyWnd, then finally the System Promoted Notification Area, window 1005E, with class ToolbarWindow32. Taking some hints from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802626/how-could-i-find-an-application-window-via-its-classid) answer, I've tried the following code:

```
win=Desktop.Instance.Get<Window>(SearchCriteria.ByNativeProperty(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Shell_TrayWnd"));
```

but when I try to run it, I get this error logged (sic):

`Exception: Error occured while geting (),AutomationElementIdentifiers.ClassNameProperty=Shell_TrayWnd`

Any ideas?

EDIT: I changed the error logging so I was getting the full traceback rather than just the exception message, and found `System.ArgumentException: Must specify at least two conditions.`

So I've modified the code to

```
win = Desktop.Instance.Get<Window>(SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Shell_TrayWnd").AndIndex(0));
```

but it's still giving the exact same error message despite my having specified two conditions.

`Exception: TestStack.White.WhiteException: Error occured while geting (),ClassName=Shell_TrayWnd,Index=0 ---> System.ArgumentException: Must specify at least two conditions.`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I tried your approach and @Rescis but I get the same error message.  Ideas?

Comment: No, I ended up leaving it for later and never got round to it. Currently that bit of the testing is still having to be done manually. I was going to try Rescis' solution at some point, but I got sidetracked with other projects and never went back.

Answer (score 1):

Within White UI Automation, there is a distinction between `SearchCriteria` and `SearchConditions`. `SearchConditions` is used internally by the framework, whereas criteria are externally added as parameters and then internally converted to conditions (and then even further converted to the Microsoft UIAutomation framework).

If you change the search criteria to

```
SearchCriteria.ByClassName("Shell_TrayWn").NotIdentifiedByText(String.Empty)
```

it will stop throwing errors.

This is because it defaults to everything being searched for by names/text as a search condition, and is throwing an irrelevant error message (it ought to be an `ArgumentException` with the message of "Must Specify a name/text condition")

Comment: Threw the same exception (v 0.13.3) for me. Here is the issue at their repo: https://github.com/TestStack/White/issues/526 - no solutions there either.

Comment: @RuNe as an FYI, the poster of that found a solution recently.

Comment: If it is the one about the popups: The exception is also thrown in other contexts. If not, where is the solution? :)

Comment: @RuNe Dohh, I don't know what I was looking at the other day.  I assume I had a couple of issues and and was looking at the wrong one.